# handling out of memory in chromium

Tags: linux, out-of-memory, raspberry-pi, chromium

I am running a web-app on a Raspberry Pi in **chromium** that should be running 24/7. The main issue is that it runs **out of memory** and displays **"He's dead Jim"**. I am wondering if someone can help me to:

1. Direct me to a chromium extension that will reload/ reboot the browser if memory runs out
2. Supply a possible cron job to detect when memory is running out and reboot the browser if that's the case

The aim is to keep chromium running everyday without human intervention. So any additional methods/ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `chromium` running? On the Rasberry Pi or on your laptop? Tell more about your web-app (show some of its source code, and give more details, including which programming language, etc....)! I would simply use an HTTP server library (like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) ...) in a C or C++ program on the Rasberry Pi.

Comment: Hi Basile and thanks for the reply. Chromium is running on the raspberry pi. Its basically a subsystem of a main system than runs a slideshow displaying images and large amounts of data in the format of graphs. The entire application is developed in grails framework and the slideshow(view) is run by jquery. Every 2 hours the graphs update the data using ajax request to load any additional data. Somehow these preiodic graph updates cause memory leaks as the memory usage is on a constant increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found the culprit to be a few ajax request that each ran every few seconds to check if the server is still up or not(it's a long story but has to be done).
Then I found a small memory-saving solution online: to put all the ajax requests in a variable and then clear the variable after use(I also cleared unused java-script variables application-wide). Here is an example below:

```
   function getData(){
        var request = $.ajax({
                url : "/someurl",
                type : "HEAD",
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    //use your data
                }
                error: function(){
                //doSomething
                },
                cache : false
            });


        //HERE IS THE HACK! :)
        data = null;
        request.onreadystatechange = null;
        request.abort = null;
        request = null;
        }

      setTimeout(function(){
         getData();
     }, 0.05 * 60 * 1000)
}
```

P.S I found the code online.